# Create SQL table from a pandas Dataframe with a lot of columns

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite

I am building a class that takes a pandas dataframe and dumps it into a SQL database, which is created by explicitly declaring all columns, like so:

```
class BuildDB:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('data/database.sqlite')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()    

    def build_league(self, df_league):
        #build table for league
        self.c.execute('CREATE TABLE LEAGUE (id number, \
                                             name text)')
        self.conn.commit()

        df_league.to_sql('LEAGUE', self.conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

---

But if a have a huge dataframe, with, say, more than 100 columns, is there a way to pass a list of columns to the SQL syntax, instead of writing all 100 entry names?

Answer (score -1):

doesn't `if_exists='replace'` take care of dropping the table and inserting these rows?

Comment: Yeah, I did not have enough points to comment. But, I wanted to know why not let pandas take care of creating the table and inserting data for you

Comment: then you could answer chnging the code above and posting your solution